# How can I have different App names on different stores?

Tags: ios, download, namespaces, store, onchange

I have app with name "Game" currently available on App Store, I want this app to appears with name "study" if any one try to download it from USA app store?

is this possible?

Comment: There is no such feature in App Store!
iOS apps are unique per App ID, which is a globally-unique Team ID plus a CFBundleIdentifier
Either you can change bundle ID and name then upload in different territory this way but this is not recommendable.

Comment: many thanks sir...when you mentioned different territory, do you mean play with availabilty option, so that the new bundle is available on different countries.

Comment: Its obvious that your bundle ID should be unique always.

Comment: You can only change app name by locale, not by App Store.  The US English locale is distinct from the UK English locale, and generally you would expect people to have their locale match their App Store country but it is not guaranteed